# Microsoft Access: Manually Changing size of text field that is primary key in 3 relationships

Tags: ms-access

I have a tiny old Microsoft Access Database with customerID that is text size 6.  customerID is the primary key of 3 tables.  If I want to change this to 9, can I safely manually delete the relationships, change the size to 9.  Do I do this in all tables?  Then recreate the relationship?

Comment: Should be able to. Make a copy of db, try it. Yes, the field size would have to be 9 in all tables. Why is this the primary key for 3 tables?

Comment: I'm not sure...I didn't make this.  I'm not even a database guy.  Just someone my uncle thinks is good with computers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do so safely. Just record every deleted relationship that you're gonna delete so you won't forget to recreate it.